# 一定間隔で、画面がタッチされている座標の情報を知ることはできますか？

Tags: swift, xcode

NSTimerなどによって、
一定間隔で、画面がタッチされている座標の情報を知ることはできますか？

タッチが動いたタイミングでなく、
こちらが決めたタイミングで、
指が画面に触れている座標を知りたいということです。

Answer (score 1):

インスタンス変数などにtouchesBeganで座標をコピーして、...Moved/Ended/Cencelledで更新・または初期化する。NSTimerに紐付けた処理にはそれを見に行かせる。必要であれば座標以外の情報もコピーしておけばよい。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。...Movedがタッチを検知する間隔は、簡単なサンプルを作って試したところ、1秒間に40回くらいなようです。その間隔よりNSTimerの間隔を小さくしたい（0.01秒）のですが、その場合に、座標の情報を更新する方法は何かありますでしょうか？